# How to properly communicate a nested protobuf schema to the confluent schema registry?

Tags: protocol-buffers, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using confluent rest-proxy interface to produce a message in Protobuf format to a Kafka topic. This message has a nested structure, in which a "Term" consists of one or more "Sections", with each "Section having an "id" and a "name".
Here is how I submit this message to Kafka:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.protobuf.v2+json" \
   -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
   --data '{"value_schema": "syntax=\"proto3\"; message Term {Sections [{string id = 1; string name = 2;}]}", "records": [{"value": [{"id": "123", "name": "Section-123"}]}]}' \
   "http://localhost:8082/topics/term"
```

I am getting this error:

```
{"error_code":42205,"message":"Invalid schema: Error when parsing raw schema. format = PROTOBUF, schema = syntax=\"proto3\"; message Term {Sections [{string id = 1; string name = 2;}]}"}
```

What changes should I make in order for this to work?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?